# What is this binding function?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading the *Handbook of Graph Theory*.

> [image]

What is binding function (I mean, what function is it? $2x?$ $2x+x^2?$)? It says that it's a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ and it might have some connection to **R3**, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal G$ be a collection of graphs ,then a  $\chi$-binding function is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ such that for any graph $G\in \mathcal G$ we have that the chromatic number of $G$ is less than or equal to $f(\omega(G))$ , where $\omega(G)$ is the clique number of $G$.

---

Examples of some trivial functions $f$ that are always binding functions:

Let $c$ be the maximum chromatic number of all the graphs in $G$, then the constant function $f(x)=c$ works.

---

Using the [Mycielskian construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian)   you can prove there is no function $f$ that is binding for every collection $\mathcal G$ of sets, since there are triangle free graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic numbers.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I understood it. $\omega(G)$ sweeps all graphs in $\mathcal{G}$, and then, one would have $$X(G_1)\leq f(\omega (G_1)), \quad X(G_2)\leq f(\omega (G_3)), \quad \ldots $$ I didn't see it before. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure no problem, just to be clear $\omega(G)$ is the cliche number of $G$ and $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$.

Comment: There's something I noticed now: Is it cliche number or clique number? Or are they different things? When I first noticed it, it seemed to be a typo.

Comment: It should be the clique number, the number of vertices in the maximum clique of $G$, I always misspell that word.

Comment: No, it was my mistake. I thought I saw it on the book.